# Open .ipynb in browser from command line

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

How do I open a `.ipynb` file in the browser from the command line? 
I've tried:

```
$ jupyter my_notebook.ipynb
```

But I get the cryptic:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'my_notebook.ipynb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It's weird because that file exists (and is readable) as named.

I'm running:

```
$ jupyter --version
4.4.0
```

Answer (score 20):

You can open a named `.ipynb` file by running either:

- `jupyter notebook my_notebook.ipynb`
- `jupyter-notebook my_notebook.ipynb`

The only difference between the two is the hyphen.

I have reported the poor error message in the question in [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3396).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Jupyter notebook, a package named NBInclude.jl can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the subcommand *'notebook'*

```
jupyter notebook my_notebook.ipynb
```